# Creating a specific process tree and terminating it

Tags: ubuntu, process, c, fork

I am currently taking a Computer Systems class and am having trouble with a homework problem. I have to create this specific process tree:

[image: Process Tree]

I also need it to stay in this state for a while (using sleep()) so a user can look it up in the terminal using pstree and see that it exists. Then it must terminate backwards (First D, then B, then C). So far, I can make the tree, but the C term terminates before the rest of the tree is made so I only end up with A->B->D. I know this is happening because of my exit(1) line, but I don't know where else to put this or if there is another way.

Code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

int status = 0;
printf("I am: %d\n\n", (int)getpid());
pid_t pid = fork(); // fork a child

if(pid == 0)
{
    printf("Hi I'm process %d and my parent is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    pid_t childPid = wait(&status);
    int childReturnValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    printf("parent knows child %d finished with return value %d\n\n", (int) childPid, childReturnValue);

    pid_t pid = fork(); // fork a child
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Hi I'm process %d and my parent is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
        pid = fork(); // fork a child
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            printf("Hi I'm process %d and my parent is %d.\n",getpid(),getppid());
            exit(3);
        }
        else
        {
            pid_t childPid = wait(&status);
            int childReturnValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("parent knows child %d finished with return value %d\n\n", (int) childPid, childReturnValue);
        }
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        pid_t childPid = wait(&status);
        int childReturnValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("parent knows child %d finished with return value %d\n\n", (int) childPid, childReturnValue);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I am currently getting:

```
I am: 2827

Hi I'm process 2828 and my parent is 2827
parent knows child 2828 finished with return value 1

Hi I'm process 2829 and my parent is 2827.
Hi I'm process 2830 and my parent is 2829.
parent knows child 2830 finished with return value 3

parent knows child 2829 finished with return value 2
```

Ideally, the line "parent knows child 2828 finished with a return value 1" should be all the way at the end. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `sleep` to prevent C to quit immediately. But in your structure, you have A waiting for C to quit before it spawns B and D.

So :

- put the `wait` bloc for C at the same place as the `wait` bloc for B
- add a sleep before the exit of C (and also before the exit of B and
  D)
- as you don't want to wait for B for double of the time, ensure the
  sleep of B is before the wait of D
- to get the correct return value for each sub-process, you should use `waitpid` instead of `wait`.

Here is the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define SLEEP_TIME 5

int main() {

int status;
printf("I am: %d\n\n", (int)getpid());
pid_t c_pid = fork(); // fork a child

if(c_pid == 0)
{
    printf("Hi I'm process C (%d) and my parent is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    pid_t b_pid = fork(); // fork a child
    if (b_pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Hi I'm process B (%d) and my parent is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
        pid_t d_pid = fork(); // fork a child
        if (d_pid == 0)
        {
            printf("Hi I'm process D (%d) and my parent is %d.\n",getpid(),getppid());
            sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            exit(3);
        }
        else
        {
            // sleep before wait - actually no effect as the wait for D also waits for SLEEP_TIME
            sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            // Wait for D to quit
            waitpid(d_pid, &status, 0);
            int DReturnValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("parent knows child D (%d) finished with return value %d\n\n", (int) d_pid, DReturnValue);
        }
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
      sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

      // Wait for B to quit
      waitpid(b_pid, &status, 0);
      int BReturnValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
      printf("parent knows child B (%d) finished with return value %d\n\n", (int) b_pid, BReturnValue);

      // Wait for C to quit
                                    waitpid(c_pid, &status, 0);
      int CReturnValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
      printf("parent knows child C (%d) finished with return value %d\n\n", (int) c_pid, CReturnValue);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is the corresponding output :

> I am: 24450
>
> Hi I'm process C (24451) and my parent is 24450
>
> Hi I'm process B (24452) and my parent is 24450.
>
> Hi I'm process D (24453) and my parent is 24452.
>
> parent knows child D (24453) finished with return value 3
>
> parent knows child B (24452) finished with return value 2
>
> parent knows child C (24451) finished with return value 1